# mapping data with kundera and cassandra: Exception in thread "main" com.impetus.kundera.query.QueryHandlerException: No entity found by the name: riro

Tags: java, cassandra, kundera

when I tried mapping data with kundera+cassandra+eclipse, I got this error:

```
Exception in thread "main" com.impetus.kundera.query.QueryHandlerException: No entity found by the name: riro
    at com.impetus.kundera.query.KunderaQuery.initEntityClass(KunderaQuery.java:403)
    at com.impetus.kundera.query.KunderaQuery.postParsingInit(KunderaQuery.java:339)
    at com.impetus.kundera.query.QueryResolver.getQueryImplementation(QueryResolver.java:78)
    at com.impetus.kundera.persistence.PersistenceDelegator.createQuery(PersistenceDelegator.java:593)
    at com.impetus.kundera.persistence.EntityManagerImpl.createQuery(EntityManagerImpl.java:384)
    at conector.main(conector.java:34)
```

my class is this:

```
import javax.persistence.Query;
import java.util.List;
import javax.persistence.EntityManager;
import javax.persistence.EntityManagerFactory;
import javax.persistence.Persistence;

public class conector
{
    public static void main(String[] args)
    {
        User user = new User();
        user.setIdEquipo("009");
        user.setFirstName("John");
        //user.setLastName("Smith");
       // user.setCity("London");

        EntityManagerFactory emf = Persistence.createEntityManagerFactory("cassandra_pu");
        EntityManager em = emf.createEntityManager();

        Query query =  (Query) em.createQuery("SELECT x FROM riro x");

        em.persist(user);
        em.close();    
        emf.close();    
   }
}
```

Comment: Is riro the name of your table corresponding to User entity ?

Comment: If you ar etrying to query table directly then you should be using em.createNativeQuery("SELECT * FROM riro "); else for JPA query use em.createQuery("SELECT x FROM User x");

Comment: I am facing this same issue. What reason could be responsible for getting this issue ?

Comment: The error being shown in my project is:

`com.impetus.kundera.query.QueryHandlerException: No entity found by the name: Employee
 at com.impetus.kundera.query.KunderaQuery.initEntityClass(KunderaQuery.java:608) ~[kundera-core-3.2.jar:na]
 at com.impetus.kundera.query.KunderaQuery.postParsingInit(KunderaQuery.java:540) ~[kundera-core-3.2.jar:na] ........

[error] m.p.EmployeeProcessImpl$ - No entity found by the name: Employee`

Please help regarding this ?

Comment: @ChhaviGangwal can you please help regarding my error ? I have also specified my question [here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/34327242/com-impetus-kundera-query-queryhandlerexception-no-entity-found-by-the-name-e). Please take a look of it and help me getting the solution to my problem.